# Java, swt, How to distinguish right-click from left-click on popup menu

Tags: java, swt, menuitem, selected, right-click

How can I distinguish right-click from left-click on popup menu in swt?

By adding a SelectionListener I can act on both left and right-click, but how
do I know which one was used? Is it possible to have a MouseListener on a MenuItem?

What I want to do is similar to a browser-favorites menu, left-click to select
and right-click for a favorite context menu.

```
Button bn = new Button(shell, SWT.FLAT);
bn.setText("Right Click to see the popup menu");

Menu popupMenu = new Menu(bn);
MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CASCADE);
newItem.setText("New");

newItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
 public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {    
      System.out.print("SELECTED1\n" );
 }
 public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      System.out.print("SELECTED2\n" );
 }
});
```

To clarify:
Sorry, did not manage to include a screen shot, but I think you can see what I mean if you follow this description.

1. Select the Favorites menu in Windows Explorer (or probably any other browser)
2. If you left-click on one of your favorites the browser will open this URL, 
   but you may also Right-click on this favorite.
3. Right-click will bring up a context menu valid for the selected favorite.

I also need two different actions for the same MenuItem (actually for the same purpose as the browser).

Comment: Ok, but select (left click) and context-menu (right click) are already included in my answer...

Comment: Yes on a button, but I hav'nt managed to do that on a MenuItem. In fact I suspect that the os only have the "selected" event for menues, and as far as I can see this event does not carry info about wich button is used. It could in a browser very well be a widget that only looks like a menu. Of course I could also do that, but it would save a lot of work if a Menu could be used.

Comment: Ok, after some testing I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to distinguish between left and right click on a `MenuItem`.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for `SWT.Selection` for the left click and `SWT.MenuDetect` for the right click:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button bn = new Button(shell, SWT.FLAT);
    bn.setText("Right Click to see the popup menu");

    Menu popupMenu = new Menu(bn);
    MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CASCADE);
    newItem.setText("New");

    bn.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            System.out.println("click");
        }
    });
    bn.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            System.out.println("menu");
        }
    });
    bn.setMenu(popupMenu);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

That said, for the menu you don't need the `SWT.MenuDetect` listener. Just calling `Button#setMenu(Menu)` does the job just fine.

Comment: ok thanks, but it's MenuItem newItem I would like detect right/Left-click for. Adding newItem.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect... does not seem to work.

Comment: @owan So what is the right click supposed to do on the menu item?

Comment: It's should open a context menu where you could remove or rename the menu item. This is almost the same as how a browser will handle a favorite (at least explorer or firefox).

Comment: @owan So you want to open a context menu from a context menu?

Comment: Well it's not really from a context menu. The popup menu will be launched from a left-click, but will it make any difference how the popup menu is launched?

Comment: @owan I still don't get it. Maybe add a step-by-step description of what you want (to your question) or maybe create a mockup image.